# Fixed Width (position:fixed) -- Fluid Width (scrollable) -- Fixed Width (scrollable)

Tags: layout, fixed, fluid-layout

Alright, I have this issue, but whenever I want to search "fixed-fluid-fixed" it brings back fixed width on the first column, not position fixed.

How do I get a 3 column layout that is like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1331627/layout.jpg

Everything I've seen has floats on everything, but that seems to screw up the fixed position menu on the right.

I'd like to have the images scale by themselves and have a fixed width 3rd column. The 2nd and 3rd columns scroll together.

Stumped.